# Unresolved external symbol error in openCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, face-recognition

I am a beginner in openCV. I have been trying out face detection and recognition in Windows platform. I have integrated different pieces of codes. I am also using PCA method to recognize the faces.I am getting an error like below,

> Error 1   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals Error 2   error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol _cvCalcEigenObjects referenced in function
>   "void __cdecl doPCA(void)" (?doPCA@@YAXXZ)     Error  3   error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol _cvEigenDecomposite referenced in function
>   "void __cdecl learn(char *)" (?learn@@YAXPAD@Z)

can someone please resolve.,..

Comment: which development environment are you using? Have you linked to the opencv lib file ?

Comment: Ya I Have  Linked all lib files... the demo Program of displaying sample images kind of programme  works fine..

Comment: And i m using Visual Studio .

Comment: under project properties - Linker - General, are the "Additional Library Directories" setup correctly ? That's assuming your not using the full path to the library under the Linker -Input tab

Comment: I have specified the OpenCv lib location..I am getting error in a function that calls cvCalcEigenObjects and cvEigenDecomposite ..Is it defined in any specific header?

Comment: do you have #include "cvaux.h"

Comment: hi keerthan have u solved this error? i seem to have the same error.. how to solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are saying that you are using VS and the demo programs of displaying images works fine.Maybe you have just added few lib files in Additional Dependencies.Go on add some more required for the function.Also it seems you want to try out PCA on your data.please see the documentation of PCA at http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=pca#PCA.And if you want some really working code visit [this page](http://www.bytefish.de/blog/pca_in_opencv). The set of input can of different database but must be gray scale and resized to same size.

Comment: For PCA related see stack question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938207/how-is-pca-implemented-on-a-camera-captured-image

Comment: cv210d.lib
cxcore210d.lib
highgui210d.lib
ml210d.lib
opencv_ffmpeg210.lib these are the lib files I have added  in additional dependencies.Is it not fine?

Comment: i think you should add imgproc210d.lib,objdetect210d.lib in addition.btw i am using opencv 2.3 and has just checked the code at the blog.it really works.if you find some unhandled exception just check check your input has been properly preprocessed.

Comment: I just checked my lib folder of OpenCV2.1 which i have installed and been working on , I m not finding the above two .lib files you specified!

Comment: I downloaded all versions of OpenCV . But i am never finding imgproc210d.lib,objdetect210d.lib files any where. Please suggest me the way to get those files.

Comment: i told you i use OpenCv 2.3.1.There are these files.But i can't tell you about OpenCv2.1.If you have just started better download Opencv 2.3.1